# How to sum a row of numbers from text file-- Bash Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, sum, rows

I'm trying to write a bash script that calculates the average of numbers by rows and columns. An example of a text file that I'm reading in is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
4 6 7 8 0
```

There is an unknown number of rows and unknown number of columns. Currently, I'm just trying to sum each row with a while loop. The desired output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 Sum = 15
4 6 7 8 0 Sum = 25
```

And so on and so forth with each row. Currently this is the code I have:

```
while read i
do
  echo "num: $i"
  (( sum=$sum+$i ))
  echo "sum: $sum"
done < $2
```

To call the program it's stats -r test_file. "-r" indicates rows--I haven't started columns quite yet. My current code actually just takes the first number of each column and adds them together and then the rest of the numbers error out as a syntax error. It says the error comes from like 16, which is the (( sum=$sum+$i )) line but I honestly can't figure out what the problem is. I should tell you I'm extremely new to bash scripting and I have googled and searched high and low for the answer for this and can't find it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you want sum=$(($sum + $i))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading the file line by line, and summing line is not an arithmetic operation. Try this:

```
while read i
do
  sum=0
  for num in $i
  do
    sum=$(($sum + $num))
  done
  echo "$i Sum: $sum"
done < $2
```

just split each number from every line using for loop. I hope this helps.

Comment: You can simplify `sum=$(($sum + $num))` to `((sum = sum + num))`.

Comment: or replace `sum=0` by `declare -i sum=0` and use `sum+=$num` with bash.

Comment: This worked exactly how I wanted it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Another non bash way (con: OP asked for bash, pro: does not depend on bashisms, works with floats).

```
awk '{c=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){c+=$i};print $0, "Sum:", c}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (not a pure `bash`):

```
while read line
do
    sum=$(sed 's/[ ]\+/+/g' <<< "$line" | bc -q)
    echo "$line Sum = $sum"
done < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`numsum -r` util](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/) covers the row addition, but the output format needs a little glue, by inefficiently `paste`-ing a few utils:

```
paste "$2" \
      <(yes "Sum =" | head -$(wc -l < "$2") ) \
      <(numsum -r "$2")
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5   Sum =   15
4 6 7 8 0   Sum =   25
```

---

Note -- to run the above line on a given file *foo*, first initialize `$2` like so:

```
set -- "" foo
paste "$2" <(yes "Sum =" | head -$(wc -l < "$2") )  <(numsum -r "$2")
```