# Multiple arguments in shell script using awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I've to make a script which will be able to sum the columns. The file looks like that:

```
1 2 3
1 2 
1
```

While executing script without the argument `./sum.sh` I get the sum of all the columns so the answer is 10. But I have to make it add only certain columns. For example `./sum.sh 1 3` should sum first and third column and give 6.

My code:

```
sum=0

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i;}; END {print sum}' plik.txt
  else
    exit 0;
fi

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    awk '{sum +="$1"} END {print sum}' plik.txt
    shift
done
```

I think that I'm quite close to the solution, but something must be missing.

Comment: There's a good solution here without using `awk`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006845/how-to-sum-a-row-of-numbers-from-text-file-bash-shell-scripting , If you are planning on doing such thing it might be better to let `awk` determine if there's one argument or more per line.

Comment: But I have to do it using awk. I know that this while chunk of code is not so bad but there is only a small part that I'm missing to achieve what I want.

Comment: The solution I provided doesn't print per line, if you want the sum to be calculated per line I need to make some small changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a combination of your script and Kent's solution

```
#!/bin/bash

file=plik.txt

if [ $# -eq 0 ];
    then
        awk     '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i} 
             END {print sum}' "$file"
    else
        awk -v cols="$*" 'BEGIN {split(cols,cs)}
                                {for(c in cs) sum+=$cs[c]}
                          END   {print sum}' "$file"    
fi
```

in action

```
$ ./sum.sh 1
3

$ ./sum.sh
10

$ ./sum.sh 1 3
6

$ ./sum.sh 1 2
7

$ ./sum.sh 1 2 3 4
10

$ ./sum.sh 1 2 3
10
```

Answer (score 2):

This one liner should work:

```
awk -v c="1 3" 'BEGIN{split(c,cols)}
               {for(x in cols)s+=$cols[x]}END{print "Sum:"s}' file
```

Note the `c="1 3"` means the columns you want to do sum, space separated. It could be set by shell script variable: `-v c="$var"`, the awk will do the calculation and output.

With your example file, the above one-liner outputs:

```
Sum:6
```

Comment: it works but I was hoping for minor upgrade of what I posted using shift.

Comment: @codddeer123 you don't need shift, just gather all the parameter, and build the `a b c d` string, and pass to the awk line

Comment: I came up with something like this: `while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    awk -v x="$1" '{sum +=$x} END {print sum}' plik.txt
  shift
done` and after executing ./sum.sh 1 2 it returns 3 and 4 so it adds up first and second column. How to add them together and get the final answer?

Comment: @codddeer123 read my comment above, "you don't need the shift"

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, no `bash` conditions required:

`awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {if(NF==1) sum+=$1;else for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i;} END{print sum}' plik.txt`

Comment: `./sum.sh 3` returns 10 and `./sum.sh 2` also returns 10 so it doesn't work. I has to sum only certain columns as I mentioned. `./sum.sh 1 3` should add up first and third column of `plik.txt` file

Comment: What do I do in a case that a column does not exist?

Comment: hmm, script can exit with info about not correct argument but for now I only want to sum chosen columns.